# How do I create a fading effect on an image, from top to bottom, and how do I over-lap that with text?

Tags: html, css, image, fading

I want an Image to have a fading effect from top to bottom, so that no matter what color the image is the text that I want to put on the image is visible.

P.S. I'm not talking about a background image, I'm talking about a regular image.
I only say this because when I look this up I see people asking how to do it with a bg image. Oh, and I want the overlaying fade to be black.

Comment: and what have you tried so far? I think you should read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use a div overlay with backgroud:rgba(0,0,0,0.1).

```
<div>
<img src="">
<div style="position:absolute;height:50px;left:0;bottom:0;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1)">Image Title</div>
</div>
```

Probably you may require to give index property as well.

Comment: what about overlapping?

Comment: Then try this:

<div>
 <div>
   <img>
 </div>
 <div>Your title</div>
</div>